# Can't download a Google drive file using WebClient

Tags: .net, download, google-drive-api, webclient

I'm trying to download a csv file from a Google drive using a vb.net app. This has worked fine for years, but today when I try to download using the app, I get a csv file that contains only this message: "Google Drive - Quota exceeded:   you can't view or download this file at this time. Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently... " But that error message can't be accurate because when I try pasting the same url into a browser, the 1.3 MB csv file I want downloads without a problem.

I've tried specifying a User-Agent header to tell Google that I'm using a browser but no improvement.

Any idea why the download works from the browser but not from WebClient? Thanks!

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub UpdateCatalog()
    Dim _WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    _WebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1HDRnj41YBWpMioLPwAFiLlK4SK8NV72C"

    '   Check if the folder already exists; if not, create it
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(My.Settings.CatalogFolder) Then
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(My.Settings.CatalogFolder)
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not create a folder to store the catalog file." & vbCr & Ex.Message,, "Folder Creation Error")
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If

    '   Check if the catalog file already exists; if so, delete it
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Settings.CatalogFile) Then My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Settings.CatalogFile)

    '   Download the new file
    Try
        _WebClient.DownloadFile(url, My.Settings.CatalogFile)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to download catalog file from Environment Canada." & vbCr & ex.Message, "Download Failure")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using for your executable? This way the community will have better idea regarding your app?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, used to work just fine. Trying to get the file using a `FileStreamResult`, only to receive the message *Sorry, you can't view or download this file at this time. Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently....*
Using the download url directly does download the file. However, using the url in a private window the same message is displayed again.

Perhaps a cookie issue related to this: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html

Or maybe a temporary Google issue?

Unfortunately have not found a solution yet.

Edit 15 feb.: It seems the files can be downloaded again, so I think it was a temporary Google issue.